# How to retain intellisense for JavaScript global variable in Visual Studio .NET 2008

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio, intellisense

I have a JavaScript wrapper that I initialize on body load and set to a global variable. Just after creating the object, I have full intellisense, but when referring to it later, from another function, the intellisense is lost. I presume this is because of dynamic typing:

```
var myWrapper;

function onload() {
    myWrapper = new Wrapper(args);
    myWrapper. //Intellisense here.
}

function whatever() {
    myWrapper. //Intellisense lost.
}
```

I get round this by pretending to create the object again before my code, and then deleting the line:

```
function whatever() {
    myWrapper = new Wrapper(); //Pretend to create object again.
    myWrapper. //Intellisense returns!
}
```

Has the inference been improved in Visual Studio 2010, or is there any way to tell JavaScript about the type of object I'm currently working on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you tell is what type it is (by using the `new` keyword, it's going to have a hard time guessing what it is...

For example, consider the following

```
var myArray;
myArray. //intellisense has no idea this is meant to be an array

var myArray = new Array();
myArray. //intellisense knows it is a array (.pop, .push, .join etc)
```

so yeah, perhaps allow your object to be set (Without args as you have) and put it at the top...

```
var myWrapper = new Wrapper();

// now whenever myWrapper is used, intellisense
// should appear (provided it knows what Wrapper is
```